# firewall-cmd --reload kicked me out from ssh command line

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, firewall

I am setting a new server and followed the instruction from [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/centos-lamp-server-apache-mysql-php/)

I followed the instruction and everything is okay until I executed this command "firewall-cmd --reload". Suddenly, I got "Network Error : Software caused connection list" error and can no longer get in on my server via SSH.

Comment: Get onto the console of the server itself and run `netstat -ano` and confirm SSH port 22 is listening. You might also run `firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-services` to ensure ssh is listed assuming the zone you are connecting is indeed "public" otherwise check the other zones too and ensure that's the interface you are connecting on for the ssh. Try running `service sshd restart` too as a simple restart of the service just in case it needs restarted. Quick ideas for you but it sounds like whatever you applied blocked ssh port  22 but it doesn't look like the article suggests doing that tho.

Comment: instructions that update firewall rules without a rollback plan for when things go awry are somewhat incomplete

Comment: JunM - Did you get a chance to figure out the issue? Did the commands I listed in the comment help any with troubleshooting and/or getting a solution?